# How to return a json in flask with the proper encoding after a POST

Tags: android, mysql, json, utf-8, flask

I am writing a webapp in flask. That gets a table from a MySQL server on a raspberry pi.

**INITIALY TESTED WITH POSTMAN**

- I set the encoding in MySQL workbench to **utf-8 bin** when creating the table.
- I set the **charset=utf8** in MySQLdb when using MySQLdb.connect(charset=utf-8)

**The original json looks like this.**

```json
{
  "Menu": [
    [
      1,
      "ΣΑΛΑΤΑ",
      "ΚΡΗΤΙΚΗ",
      5.5
    ],
    [
      2,
      "ΣΑΛΑΤΑ",
      "ΦΑΚΗ",
      6
    ]
  ]
}
```

**This is the return json (POSTMAN)**

```json
{
  "Menu": [
    [
      1,
      "ΣΑΛΑΤΑ",
      "ΚΡΗΤΙΚΗ",
      5.5
    ],
    [
      2,
      "ΣΑΛΑΤΑ",
      "ΦΑΚΗ",
      6
    ]
  ]
}
```

**SO FAR IN POSTMAN IT WORKS JUST FINE**

**NOW WHEN I WANT TO print it on the webpage it appears as this:**

```json
{
  "Menu": [
    [
      1,
      "\u03a3\u0391\u039b\u0391\u03a4\u0391",
      "\u039a\u03a1\u0397\u03a4\u0399\u039a\u0397",
      5.5
    ],
    [
      2,
      "\u03a3\u0391\u039b\u0391\u03a4\u0391",
      "\u03a6\u0391\u039a\u0397",
      6.0
    ]
  ] 
}
```

**AND ALSO WHEN I POST FROM THE ANDROID APPLICATION THE SAME ISSUE.**

to return the json i am using `jsonify`.

Comment: What do you see when you `print` inside python? Have you included `<meta charset=utf-8>` in your HTML file?

Comment: i am simply returning to the screen there is no html code. just `jsonify({'Menu':menu})`. with or without `app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False` the effect is the same. it only appears correctly on **POSTMAN**

Answer (score 1):

That is valid JSON, with unicode characters escaped so that the value is ASCII.

If you actually parse the JSON in JavaScript, you will still get the correct values.  Assuming you called your endpoint with an AJAX request, you would load the data in the callback with `JSON.parse`.  Some AJAX libraries may handle this for you.

```javascript
var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);
```

You can stop `jsonify` from escaping everything to ASCII by disabling `JSON_AS_ASCII`.  You should avoid doing this, since this can result in invalid characters in the response.

```
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
```

Preferrably, leave the data as is and use it from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me:

```
app.json.ensure_ascii = False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).